# Find a variable in the equation

Tags: math, numerical-methods

Given the equation (`depth = log(c * p + 1) / log(c * 1000 + 1) * p`)
How can I find p?

I wanted to get an equation with `p = sqrt(exp(...` or something like this

Comment: You can't because `p` exist both inside and outside a logarithm, Your only option is a numerical method with an approximate solution.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Not a programming question, at first glance I guess. (I didn't downvote).

Comment: Please give us some sample values to test code. Also what programming environment do you operate under?

Comment: Ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: This question _is_ programming related since it involves a numerical method for solution.

Comment: @ja72: No, it isn't programming related, because he's asking for a closed-form solution, at least how I read it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question.

Comment: You could use a non-linear solver, `p=fsolve(@(x) depth*x*log(1+1000*c) - log(1+c*x), 1)` or similar, asking about details of this or your own root-finding implementation (bisection, secant, Newton) is again on-topic. // It would also help if you could give typical values or value ranges for the parameters of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The isn't an analytical solution to problems like this because they contain the variable both inside and outside a transcendental function like `log()`.

With some quick algebra, you can simplify the expression to

```
p*log(1 + c*p) = b
```

where `b=depth*log(1+1000*c)` is a constant.

I propose using a single point iteration, to get a numeric result.

Start with some guess of `p=1` or something and then do a loop until you converge to a value of (`c#` shown below).

```cs
b = depth*log(1+1000*c);
p = 1;
do 
{
    p_old = p;
    p = b/log(1+c*p);
}
while( abs(p-p_old)> 1e-6);
```

and hope it converges soon.